# Is there an option to see changed lines/files even if changes were committed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After commit all the changes I'm unable to see which files and lines were changed. I'd like to see them and know that I changed them even if they were committed.

Is there an option to see changes after commit?

Comment: changes compared to what? `HEAD~1`?, you can compare commits.

Comment: `git log -p` or `git show` or `git diff <branch to compare to | commit sha>`